# MsAccess Database

Tags: c#, string, connection-string, oledb, slash

I'm trying to have my `connection string` to connect to my Access database but I encountered this problem.

When I wrote this as the connection string:

```
string cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\prjThesis\STUD_RECORD.accdb";
```

The back slashes were marked red and an error message says `Unrecognized escape sequence` pointing to the slashes.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Use @ before the string or double slashes.

```
string cs = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\prjThesis\STUD_RECORD.accdb";
```

or

```
string cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\prjThesis\\STUD_RECORD.accdb";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [*`verbtaim string literals`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like this;

```
string cs = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\prjThesis\STUD_RECORD.accdb";
```

Or you can use double slash (`\\`) in your code without verbtaim literal;

```
string cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\prjThesis\\STUD_RECORD.accdb";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\` (they mean `\` in an ordinary string literal):

```
string cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\prjThesis\\STUD_RECORD.accdb"
```

...or verbatim string literals:

```
string cs = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\prjThesis\STUD_RECORD.accdb"
```